# How can I display the "Message sent successful" after completing the form

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display the "Message sent successful" after someone fills in the form.

here is my code

```
<form action="contact.php" id="footer-form" method="post" role="form">
<div class="form-group has-feedback"><label class="sr-only" for="name2">Name</label> <input class="form-control" id="name2" name="name2" placeholder="Name" required="" type="text" /></div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback"><label class="sr-only" for="email2">Email address</label> <input class="form-control" id="email2" name="email2" placeholder="Enter email" required="" type="email" /></div>

<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Send" /></form>

<?php 

$name = $_POST['name2'];
$email = $_POST['email2'];
$formcontent="From: $name \nEmail: $email";
$recipient = "email@domain.com";
$subject = "Website Under Construction";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";


mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What keeps you from adding it to the given code?

Answer (score 0):

Just put your PHP Code above your HTML Code and define a message.

Then, just echo it in your HTML Code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST) {
   $name = $_POST['name2'];
   $email = $_POST['email2'];
   $formcontent="From: $name \nEmail: $email";
   $recipient = "email@domain.com";
   $subject = "Website Under Construction";
   $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

   // Set the message here:
   $message = "Message sent!";
}

?>

<form action="contact.php" id="footer-form" method="post" role="form">
<div class="form-group has-feedback"><label class="sr-only" for="name2">Name</label> <input class="form-control" id="name2" name="name2" placeholder="Name" required="" type="text" /></div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback"><label class="sr-only" for="email2">Email address</label> <input class="form-control" id="email2" name="email2" placeholder="Enter email" required="" type="email" /></div>

<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Send" /></form>

<?php
// Put this wherever you want
if(isset($message)) echo $message;
?>
```

### Explanation

By default, the variable `$message` is unset. When the form submission is completed, you assign the variable `$message` the string "Message sent!".

Now, anywhere in your code, you can check if the variable `$message` is defined and print it out.

Comment: Ok, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

**index.php** file

```
<form action="contact.php" id="footer-form" method="post" role="form">
 <div class="form-group has-feedback"><label class="sr-only"for="name2">Name</label> 
<input class="form-control" id="name2" name="name2" placeholder="Name" required="" type="text" /></div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback"><label class="sr-only" for="email2">Email address</label>  <input class="form-control" id="email2" name="email2" placeholder="Enter email" required="" type="email" /></div>

 <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="send_mail" value="Send" /> 
</form>
```

**contact.php** file

```
if (isset($_POST['send_mail'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name2'];
    $email = $_POST['email2'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \nEmail: $email";
    $recipient = "email@domain.com";
    $subject = "Website Under Construction";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

    $send_email = mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
    if ($send_email) {
       echo 'Your success message';
    } else {
       die("Error!");
    }
 }
```

**Explanation**

First look `index.php` file, `<form action="contact.php" id="footer-form" method="post" role="form">` here used `action` `attribute` on form tag and used `action` path like `contact.php`

And also check `<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="send_mail" value="Send" />` here I used `name` attribute `name="send_mail"`

When a user click on this button, this page will redirect to `contact.php` page and this page will check user click or not on button and process the `mail` function. After process, finally show the message.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: First look `index.php` file, `<form action="contact.php" id="footer-form" method="post" role="form">` here used `action` `attribute` on form tag and used action path like "contact.php". and  also check `<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="send_mail" value="Send" />` here I used `name` `attribute` `name="send_mail"`

When a user click on `send_mail` button, this page will redirect to `contact.php` page and this page will check `send_mail`  button and process `mail` function.

Comment: Ok, I will try that